# GStreamer video on DSI screen without X

Tags: display, dsi

I'm using the official (DSI) touchscreen and want to use GStreamer to display video output on it. What is the appropriate sink to use if no X-server is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the open graphics driver, you probably want the [kmssink](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761059) and the  [drm-vc4-dsi](https://github.com/anholt/linux/tree/drm-vc4-dsi) branch of the kernel.

Comment: And using the standard kernel branch?

Answer (score 0):

**glimagesink** should be able to display video on the official screen, but continues to be [broken](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/repo/issues/4) (2016-04-16).